# Express optional parameters

Tags: node.js, express

I want a path like so: `/skittles?type[]=blue&type[]=green` (just like a `x-www-form-urlencoded`, but this is a get request for an api).

So if I have the following code, how would I add the optional parameters to the route path (currently /skittles)?

```
app.get('/skittles', callback);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add them to the path.  You'll find them in the `req.query` object.

```
var util = require('util');

app.get('/skittles', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query);
  var type = req.query.type || [];
  console.log("type: "+util.inspect(type));
  res.send("Type: "+util.inspect(type));
});
```

Comment: You even _can't_ add them to the route.

Answer (score -1):

you can validate your input request parameters what you have received in your req.body or req.query like this..

```
app.post('/v1/api/test-api', function(req, res) {
   var parameters = [];
   if(req.body.userName !== undefined) {
       //DO SOMEHTING
       parameters.push({username: req.body.userName});
   }
   if(req.body.userId !== undefined) {
       //DO SOMEHTING

       parameters.push({userId: req.body.userId});
   }
   if(req.body.userEmail !== undefined) {
      //DO SOMEHTING
       parameters.push({userEmail: req.body.userEmail});
   }

   res.json({receivedParameters: parameters});

});
```